# Our iOS developer has developed a game in Unity3D. How do we export it for Android?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Our iOS developer has developed a game in Unity3D. How do we export it for Android? I did a quick check on the internet and it says there "one click export for Android".

Is this really the case? Are there ways it might have been developed that will make it not as easy to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186614/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-my-apple-apps-into-android-apps

Comment: Build settings -> Android -> switch to -> build.

Comment: Will there be any additional work necessary to adapt it for Android?

Comment: @anothertest this is irrelevant, the guy asking this has developed his apps natively for iOS using Xcode. Im asking about a unity3d which is supposed to be independent one-for-all platform

Comment: it all depends on whether they used any additional libraries (not provided by unity) and if those libraries are ios specific or not.

Comment: If you're using native libraries, you'll need them for Android as well. I'd suggest, do just switch the platform to Android, build it, and do a lot of testing, to check if really everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about "one click export for Android" then yes it is a one click export for Android

> Build Settings > Android > Switch platform > Build

But for the question will there be any additional work necessary. Well that depends if you have used any (self made or third party) plugins in your application. If not then no additional work is necessary.

If yes, then there are 3 possibilities:

1. All the (third party) plugins are only iOS specific.
2. Some of them have both Android and iOS component in them.
3. You have written your own plugins.

Then, (as you said that you have developed an iOS only application) it is obvious that all the code you wrote using those plugins is also iOS specific. In that case it is recommended that you enclose all that code in Unity's [Platform Dependent Compilation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) checks (for iOS it is `UNITY_IOS` for android it is `UNITY_ANDROID`).

This is recommended because initially you should first check if your application runs perfectly on android devices with out any 'plugins' nightmare. Once sure, then you can go ahead and implement the Android side of all those plugins.

These checks only ensure that the piece of code written inside these are executes only on the respected platforms. Meaning, enclosing all iOS specific code in `#if UNITY_IOS` will not disturb you iOS build but only prevent that code from running on any platform other than iOS.

Finally, After that you are good to go and follow that "one click export for Android" method.